# Retrieve GitHub contents from private repo not working in Firefox

Tags: github, firefox, axios, httprequest, github-api

The following code works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module">
      import axios from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios';

      const response = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/contents/PATH', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `token <TOKEN>`,
          Accept: 'application/vnd.github.raw',
        },
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log(response.data);
      } else {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        console.error('Failed to fetch content:', response.statusText);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make it work in Firefox?! I need to be able to fetch the contents of a file.

"Fetch" in Firefox work completely different? How can I achieve the same thing but in Firefox?!